# Why does my mint function throw an insufficent amount error?

Tags: remix, erc-721, payable, mint, remix-tests

I'm testing a smart contract on **REMIX**, everything works but the mint function provided throws an insufficient amount error even though I have enough ether in my account.

It seems like theirs no ether being sent out.
Any idea why this might be happening ?

[image]

**Code**

```
uint256 public cost = 0.02 ether;

function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
 require(!paused, "The contract is paused!");
 require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "Need to send 0.02 ether");

 _mintLoop(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
}
```

- The contract is not paused
- I have enough ether in my account

[The entire contract | MINT FUNCTION LINE 55](https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_contract/blob/main/contract/SimpleNftLowerGas.sol)

Answer (score 0):

You have to send wei through the value attribute

I used this [converter](https://eth-converter.com/)

[image: code]